# Capturing url within text by using regex in xslt code

Tags: regex, url, xslt-2.0

This is my test input:

```
<license>
     <p>some text (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/) some text.</p>
</license>
```

Desired output:

```
<license xlink:href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/">
     <p>some text (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/) some text.</p> 
</license>
```

Basically I am trying to copy the url inside the text where `license` element does not contain the attribute `xlink:href="http:// ******">` by
looking in child `<license-p>` and move any URL up to the `xlink:href` attribute on the parent (license)

and here is my xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"

exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="3.0"> 
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="license">
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="xlink:href">                    
                <xsl:value-of select='replace(p,"[\s\S]*" ,"(\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&amp;@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&amp;@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&amp;@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&amp;@#\/%=~_|$]))")'/>
            </xsl:attribute> 
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p/@xlink:href"/>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The regex I am using is not working for saxon owing characters like?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `replace()` here?

Comment: I am allowed to use 3 functions with regex expressions. matches(), replace() and tokenize(). The purpose of replace() is to extract the uri from the whole text by replacing entire text content with uri. matches() returns true or false. and tokenize  function splits a string based on a regular expression. I can also use analyze-string() instead of replace()

Comment: If you want to extract a certain substring matching a regular expression then you should consider using `xsl:analyze-string` instead of `replace`, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#analyze-string

Comment: Also in the sample the URI is wrapped into `()`, can we assume that that is always the case?

Comment: No, I am afraid we cannot assume that the URI will always be wrapped into ()

Comment: Sure, I can definitely use analyze-string(). But at the end of the day it requires a xpath friendly regex which grabs the uri from a chunk of text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok folks, I know regex is far from perfect but the following works for me:

```
<xsl:analyze-string 
    select="$elValue"
    regex="((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file):(()|(\\\\))+[\\w\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\+-=\\\\\\.&amp;]*\w*.\w*\W\w*\W\w*\W\d.\d\W)">                    
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>                       
        </xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```